# SwiftUI - How to change properties on an Image view that's stored inside a static list?

Tags: arrays, image, properties, swiftui, static-variables

I have a list of SwiftUI Image views that's stored inside a static variable in a class. I need to change some properties of the Image when it's being displayed. Though the properties won't autocomplete in. I've also had some of the properties not work when I add them. Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

extension Image: Identifiable {
    public var id: UUID {
        return UUID()
    }
}

class ImageClass: Identifiable {
    static var imageList = [Image(systemName: "circle"), Image(systemName: "circle.fill")]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(ImageClass.imageList, id: \.id) { image in
            image.foregroundColor(.red) // autocomplete doesn't work, sometimes properties don't work
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: With Xcode 12 all works well.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store use a `View` as a `static` variable. (Since they could live in the memory forever). Instead, you may want to use an `enum`:

```
enum ImageName: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    var id: ImageName { self } // could be any other id you need

    case circle
    case circleFill = "circle.fill"

    var image: Image { Image(systemName: self.rawValue) }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(ImageName.allCases) {
                $0.image.foregroundColor(.red) // Auto complete works like a charm
            }
        }
    }
}
```